# Fluid layout with background image

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have an image that is 1020px wide and repeats (as per the css) vertically. This creates a nice drop shadow at the edge of the containing div. Problem is when the div is shrunk the image does not shrink with the containing div? I need the image to shrink with the div but it stays at a fixed width? I am new to fluid layouts after building with px for years! Any ideas welcome.

Note that I was unable to create a fiddle because I could not find a way to load the shadow.jpg file!

Code is here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stuck!</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #main-container {margin: 0px auto; border: 2px solid blue; width: 100%; max-width: 1020px; background-image: url(shadow.jpg); background-repeat: repeat-y;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main-container" style="height: 1228px"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @SuperScript I tried to but could not upload the shadow.jpg file into fiddle. Not sure how to!

Comment: @Margate upload/host the shadow.jpg somewhere and include the absolute url in your inline css: `background-image: url('http://path/to/image.jpg');`